# How to make typescript treat two keyof as same type

Tags: typescript, typescript-types

I want to make a reducer to modify an appollo search variable.

```js
type SearchReducer = Reducer<
  WhereInput,
  { key: keyof WhereInput; value: WhereInput[keyof WhereInput] }
>;

useReducer<SearchReducer>((prev,{key,value})=>{
    const newValue = {...prev};
    // compile failure here
    newValue[key] = value;
    return newValue;
})
```

It said that I can't assume newValue[key] share the same type with value, I think it is right but how can I restrict that two keyof in my type must be the same value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To restrict key and value your SearchReducer type can be rewritten as follows:

```
type SearchReducer<T extends keyof WhereInput> = Reducer<
  CaseWhereInput,
  { key: T; value: WhereInput[T] }
>;
```

It's hard to give you a complete solution though since I am not familiar with any of the types you are using or the appollo search you mention (CaseWhereInput, WhereInput, Reducer) or the signature useReducer function.

Comment: Thanks for help, but I think I cannot use generic here, because the reducer is not work for a single key of the object, it work for every key of the object. And use generic mean I need to make a reducer for each key, I don't need key here and just have.
type SearchReducer<T extends keyof WhereInput> = Reducer<
  WhereInput,
  value: WhereInput[T]
>;

Comment: May be if you update your question and include the type definitions missing, or include a link to a typescript playground showing the problem, it would be easier to help.